# Postgresql how to sum across two different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a two tables:

```
|currency_type|user_id|amount|
|-------------|-------|------|
|          aaa|    404|  2000|
|          bbb|    404|   300|
|          ccc|     22|   444|
```

```
|currency_type|user_id|balance|
|-------------|-------|-------|
|          aaa|    404|     30|
|          xxx|    404|     50|
```

How can i get sum of both tables (**amount** + **balance**) for each **currency_type** respectively? Example of result for **user_id** = 404
And performance is matter for me, so faster is better.

```
|currency_type|user_id|    sum|
|-------------|-------|-------|
|          aaa|    404|   2030|
|          bbb|    404|    300|
|          xxx|    404|     50|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table t1 (currency_type text,user_id int,amount int);
create table t2 (currency_type text,user_id int,balance int);

insert into t1 values
('aaa',    404,  2000),
('bbb',    404,   300),
('ccc',     22,   444);

insert into t2 values
('aaa', 404, 30),
('xxx', 404, 50);

with t1t2 as (
  select currency_type, user_id, amount from t1
  union all
  select currency_type, user_id, balance as amount from t2
)
select currency_type, user_id, sum(amount)
from t1t2
where user_id = 404
group by currency_type, user_id
```

**Result**

> ```
> currency_type | user_id |  sum
> :------------ | ------: | ---:
> aaa           |     404 | 2030
> bbb           |     404 |  300
> xxx           |     404 |   50
> ```

**Example**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=89c7d5b9ee8d5ce1eb42ee5cda961d0c

**Explanation**

Just combine both tables but rename balance as amount for just the time being in the query. Now you'd have balances and amounts in the same table. All that remains is total up the amount column for each currency_type/user_id combination.